# Referencing list items containing json

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm trying to write a social network parser just for fun.

```
import requests
import json

it = -1
items = []
for u in range(1):
    source = {"response": {"count": 94858, "items": [{"first_name": "Mariya", "id": 3s4v8n1d5, "last_name": "Potapova", "can_write_private_message": 0, "track_code": "85xg"}, {"first_name": "\u041f\u043e\u043b\u044f", "id": v9b06g045, "last_name": "\u041c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u044c", "can_write_private_message": 0, "track_code": "ac1b5c1w"}]}}
    e = 0
    while (e < len(source)):
        items.append(source.get('response', {}).get('items', {}))
        e += 1
#     sleep(randint(1,2))
    it = it + 1

print(json.dumps(items, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```

I need to bring the output to a certain form so that I can work with it further. It is necessary to output from the source only the parameters inside the list:
At the moment, the output looks like this:

```
[
    [
        {
            "first_name": "Mariya",
            "id": v4b284b55,
            "last_name": "Potapova",
            "can_write_private_message": 0,
            "track_code": "85dd5caxg"
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Иван",
            "id": 13b0v4b75,
            "last_name": "Мартьянов",
            "can_write_private_message": 0,
            "track_code": "ace1rUwuuw"
        }
    ]
]
```

How can make that this output is only in one list and you can refer to each item in the list?
For example:

```
print(json.dumps(items[0], indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
-----
        {
            "first_name": "Mariya",
            "id": v4b284b55,
            "last_name": "Potapova",
            "can_write_private_message": 0,
            "track_code": "85dd5caxg"
        }
```

Comment: `source` is a string, you can't use `source.get()`. You have to parse it to a dictionary with `json.loads()`.

Comment: Use `items.extend()` instead of `items.append()` if you want to concatenate a list to it.

Comment: What's the point of the `while (e < len(source)):` loop? You never use `e` for anything.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your code is not minimal: you have included code unrelated to the problem.  You say that you're working on the output form, but you have overhead code that does input processing not related to the internal organization.

Comment: Please work through a tutorial on JSON formatting in Python so that you can code that part cleanly.  Explain the *specific* problem with your code -- leaving us multiple problems to fix, with a vague "I want my output to be different", is not a well-formed SO quesiton.

Comment: What is the purpose of the for loop `for u in range(1):`. You do not use `u` inside the loop, so it seems you can just remove the loop. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Unclear what all the indicies are needed for, but you should loop over the items list to extract them rather than add a list to a list

```
items = []
source = {"response": {"count": 94858, "items": [{"first_name": "Mariya", "id": 3s4v8n1d5, "last_name": "Potapova", "can_write_private_message": 0, "track_code": "85xg"}, {"first_name": "\u041f\u043e\u043b\u044f", "id": "v9b06g045", "last_name": "\u041c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u044c", "can_write_private_message": 0, "track_code": "ac1b5c1w"}]}}
resp = source.get('response', {})
for item in resp.get('items', []):
  items.append(item)

print(json.dumps(items, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Or, simply, `items = resp.get('items', []):`